# MFMailComposeViewController send and cancel buttons are not working if the view has custom UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

[image]

Hi,

As in the  above image, My viewcontroller class has a customnavigationbar, when I am trying to compose an email using MFMailComposeViewController, the navigationbar of MFMailComposeViewController view is getting covered by but my custom navigationbar. So I was unable to click on the "Cancel" and "Send" button's.

I tried both 
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES  & 
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]

but the navigation bar just won't go away. Anyone have suggestions for this?

Comment: are you hiding your navigation bar after pushing the mail composer???

Comment: actually this MFMailComposeViewController is in SAAboutUsViewController (UIViewController). I am adding this view controller as a subview to the currentview controller like this:  if (!aboutUsViewController) {
  aboutUsViewController = [[SAAboutUsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SAAboutUsViewController" bundle:nil];
  [aboutUsViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 418)];
  [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];

Comment: What happens if you do setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 416)?

Comment: I solved the issue. The problem is I tried to present MFMailComposeViewController on a view rather that on a viewcontroller. I modified the code accordingly it started working.